# How to show an alert message to a user with Event Listener

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have created an Event called `UserWalletNewTransaction.php` and added this to it:

```
public $transaction;

public function __construct($transaction) {
    $this->$transaction = $transaction;
}
```

Now in order to fire this event at the Controller, I coded this:

```
$newTransaction = UserWalletTransaction::create(['user_id' => $user_id, 'wallet_id' => $wallet_id, 'creator_id' => $creator_id, 'amount' => $amount_add_value, 'description' => $trans_desc]);

event(new UserWalletNewTransaction($newTransaction));
```

Then at the Listener, `UserWalletNotification.php`, I tried:

```
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event) {
    $uid = $event->transaction->user_id;
    $user = User::find($uid);
    // now sends alert message to the user
}
```

So the scenario is, when Admins create a new Transaction for a custom user, a new alert message must be sent for him/her to let him/her know that new transaction was added for him/her.

But I don't really know how to do that.. So if you know, please let me know, I would really appreciate that...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean `alert message`?  it's should be email or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different things you can do in terms of "alerting" the customer.

One route would be to send an email or text message in your event listener. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail for help doing it via email.

Another way would be using browser push notifications. You could use [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) for this. You would setup the front end to display an alert to a customer user asking if they would like to subscribe to push notifications. When they subscribe, you will get back an ID for that specific user. Make an API call to your Laravel app, and store that ID in the users table (you will need a migration). Then from within your event listener, you can make a call to OneSignal's API and send the user a notification, which will popup on their computer.

Here is an example of using OneSignal to send an event to a user via the API:

Your OneSignal service:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\User;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class OneSignalService
{
    public function sendNotificationToUser(User $user, string $title, string $message, string $url, string $subtitle = null)
    {
        if (!$user->one_signal_id) {
            return;
        }
        $fields = [
            'app_id' => config('services.onesignal.app_id'),
            'include_player_ids' => [$user->one_signal_id],
            'headings' => ['en' => $title],
            'contents' => ['en' => $message],
            'url' => $url,
        ];
        if ($subtitle) {
            $fields['subtitle'] = ['en' => $subtitle];
        }
        $client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/',
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization' => 'Basic <<API_KEY>>',
            ]
        ]);
        $client->request('POST', 'notifications', [
            'json' => $fields
        ])
    }
}
```

UserWalletNotification:

```
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event) {
    $uid = $event->transaction->user_id;
    $user = User::find($uid);
    // now sends alert message to the user
    $oneSignal = new OneSignalService();
    $oneSignal->sendNotificationToUser($user, 'New Transaction', 'You have a new transaction', 'yourwebsite.com');
}
```

The way I would go about this would be via [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting), which would use websockets to instantly send the customer user an alert to their browser, in which you could then display a popup of some sort. You could install [Laravel Echo Server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server), but to keep things simple you can use [Pusher](https://pusher.com/). Follow the guide to install on the front end of your website.

Then, create a private channel specific to a customer user "transaction.created.{{USER ID}}" and listen for it on your front end.

Within Laravel you will install the [PHP Pusher SDK](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php) via composer.

Then within your .env file set:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```

Next, open up channels.php within your routes directory in Laravel and add:

```
Broadcast::channel('transaction.created.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

This will verify authentication for your user to the private channel.

Create an Laravel Event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TransactionCreated implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user = null;
    public $transaction = null;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, UserWalletTransaction $transaction)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->transaction = $transaction;
    }

    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return $this->transaction->toArray(); //Or whatever information you want to send to the front end
    }

    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {
        return 'TransactionCreated';
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('transaction.created.' . $this->user->id);
    }
}
```

Fire the event from UserWalletNotification:

```
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event) {
    $uid = $event->transaction->user_id;
    $user = User::find($uid);
    // now sends alert message to the user
    event(new TransactionCreated($user, $event->transaction));
}
```

Lastly, create some sort of popup and display it on the front end when your callback function for the private channel is hit.

If you need anymore help, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

If by alert you mean showing a message on the web interface, use flash data.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#flash-data

```
$newTransaction = UserWalletTransaction::create(...);

event(new UserWalletNewTransaction($newTransaction));

$request->session()->flash('status', 'Transaction done.');

return view(...)
```

```xml
<span>{{ session('status') }}</span>
```

If you mean sending an email, just use the `Mail` facade in your listener to send a mailable.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#sending-mail

```
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event) {
    $uid = $event->transaction->user_id;
    $user = User::find($uid);

    Mail::to($user)->send(new TransactionDoneMail($event->transaction)); // TransactionDoneMail being your mailable class, made with "php artisan make:email TransactionDoneMail"
}
```

There are nice examples on how to build a mailable class in the documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#writing-mailables

Comment: The alert is only for the user of website that Admin submits a transaction for him. And I need to do this in Listener, not the Controller. The controller is for the Admin of the website and I don't want to redirect Admin to the view of users.  I just need to notify user that he has a new Transaction.

Comment: @tejoslaeslio this is not possible, you will need to do this frontend as said you can use pusher, laravel echo its pretty simple to setup https://pusher.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do I believe, is **asynchronous notifications**.

Well, if you really mean flash messages - those who are stored in session - it will not be so easy.

Normal steps are create flash message for the user currently logged in on a website, stored in session that is unique for the current user. It can be shown only for this user.

What you want is to create flash message as the admin (from admin perspective) , then only to admin it can be shown.

I would do this, create new table, when these notification messages will be stored. Some table with columns like `id, user_id, message, type, created_date, shown_date`. Admins will put alert/notification messages for each user. Then create class (can be in controller for example) that will check this table for each user and if there is new not already shown message, show it normally in flash message for that current user. Dont forget to mark that message as shown. That is it.

So much for custom solution. I belive there must be some for example jQuery/other Jvascript plugins or Laravel plugins for **asynchronous notifications**, please check those.